# Visual Studio custom wizard - add additional configuration

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, configuration, build

I am writing a visual studio custom wizard for creating C++ project.

I need to define additional build configuration, that inherits the debug configuration.

I googled a lot, but couldn't find anything.

I guess this should be done in the JScript file (`default.js`), `AddConfig` function, by calling `proj.Object.AddConfiguration`. But I couldn't find examples, nor syntax rules.

The only thing I found is : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/200039/A-Visual-Studio-Wizard-to-add-more-project-configu but it is way too complicated, and I couldn't figure it out.

Can you please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it. It can be done using C# code:

```
solution.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations.Add("Conf", "Debug", true);
//set Conf to be active build configuration
solution.SolutionBuild.SolutionConfigurations.Item("Conf").Activate();
//Get project
VCProject pro = solution.Projects.Item(1).Object;
//Get comiler tool for project
VCCLCompilerTool tool = pro.Configurations.item("Conf").Tools("VCCLCompilerTool");
//set Prprocessor definition for Conf
tool.PreprocessorDefinitions = "NEW";
```